# How to download a video from the web?

Tags: c#, download, webclient, http-status-code-403, downloadfileasync

From here i get the json:

> https://my.mail.ru/+/video/meta/1537606332146778160

I have a video link:

> http://cdn29.my.mail.ru/hv/7590086.mp4?slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fvideo-cephgw2.i%3A8001%2Frados%2F7590086-hv&p=f&expire_at=1551808800&touch=1389788866&reg=202&sign=d7c3cfa0753f312b99cc2f9d2512a2fad1f78e86&seekSchema=3&key=1080P

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string dowloadLink = "https:" + textBoxUrl.Text + "&seekSchema=" + labelSeekSchema.Text + "&key=" + labelFileQuality.Text;
        listBoxDownload.Items.Add(lblFileName.Text);
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)");                         
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(dowloadLink), @"C:\\Temp\test.mp4");
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        });
        thread.Start();
}
```

When I try to download it, I get a file of size 0.

Here is the answer postman:
`403 Forbidden Time:104 ms Size:298 B`

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →http://my.mail.ru
Content-Length →0
Date →Tue, 05 Mar 2019 15:43:21 GMT
Content-Type →text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

What is wrong?

Comment: are you authorized to get the file?

Comment: Not. Isn't it generally available?

Comment: No. You can try this in private browser window or in another browser.

Comment: HTTP 403.  And what to do in this case?

Comment: Added authorization: `client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic YS5kaWVs.....................");`.  Did not help

Comment: Try to add the header like that: client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + base64EncodedPassword);

Comment: @momo didn't work either

Comment: do you still have the http status code 403? how do you encode your password?

Comment: I check the request in postman. Postman itself generates base auth. Encode64.

Comment: you probably use a different url. For example the one you provided is with the http protocol, but the one you actually try in your code uses https. Try to print the url to the console and use it in postman. If it still doesn't work than there must be a problem with a header or encoding.

Comment: I checked both options.

Comment: How do you know it is acutally a video _file_ and not just some streaming endpoint URL?

Comment: I get this link from json. If I open the link in the browser, then by right-click I can download the video file in the format mp4